# Shear Stress / Flexure Stress Formulas / Tables

Tags: stresses, moments, shear

Is there something similar to the Section Modulus in the Flexure Formula

$$\rho_{max} = \dfrac{M_{max}}{S}$$

where $S = \dfrac{I}{c}$ for shear stress formula?

So in

$$\tau_{max} = \dfrac{VQ}{IT}$$

then there should be a Shear Section Modulus published which would be $Q(\text{of centroid}) / IT$

So you can get $\tau_{max} = V * \text{Shear Section Modulus}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is commonly referred to as the **shear area** of the section (see [here](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/robot-structural-analysis-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Robot/files/GUID-50986085-D4AB-41C5-9B21-CF9619B8EB8B-htm.html) for a list of shear areas).

Consider a solid rectangle with depth 20mm and width 10mm. From [this calculator](https://skyciv.com/free-moment-of-inertia-calculator) we can see that the section properties are:

$I = 6667 \text{ mm}^4$

$Q = 500 \text{ mm}^3$

$t = 10 \text{ mm}$

So the shear area is:

$A_{s} =\dfrac{It}{Q}=\dfrac{(6667)(10)}{500} = 133.3 \text{ mm}^2$

Therefore the shear stress is:

$\tau_{max}=\dfrac{VQ}{It}=\dfrac{V}{A_s} = \dfrac{V}{133.3 \text{ mm}^2}$

Compare this to the [resource](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/robot-structural-analysis-products/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/Robot/files/GUID-50986085-D4AB-41C5-9B21-CF9619B8EB8B-htm.html) I shared earlier and you can see that for a thick walled rectangular section the shear area (denoted by W in the resource) is:

$A_s=\dfrac{2}{3}hb = \dfrac{2}{3}(20)(10) = 133.3 \text{ mm}^2$